# No previous knowledge of programming, considering electrical engineering

Tags: sensor

I am still at school and wont finish until 2015 but i have seen people control doors, toy cars etc with their iphones and i really want to get in to something like that.

I have a lot of spare time and was wondering where i would start, i want to try some projects that help my understanding of electronics and also help me decide if this field is really for me.

I have no idea how they control toy cars, doors, tv's so i would really appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Electrical Engineering. On this site, we want questions to be _reasonable scoped_. That is, your question shouldn't be too broad or too localized. As this question stands now, it's likely to get closed as too broad. Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: This question is an example of [this](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/428/17592).

Answer (score 4):

While this question is not within the norms for this site, it is one frequently asked, so here is an outline, take it where you will:

- It would behoove you to get a couple of books to gather a preliminary understanding of electronic design in general, e.g.

  - [Practical Electronics for Inventors, Third Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071771336),
  - [Starting Electronics Construction: Techniques, Equipment and Projects](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750667362),
  - [Getting Started in Electronics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0945053282)
- Read up on the various hobbyist electronics sites, and forums of hobby-friendly electronics platforms (such as, dare I say it, [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/forum/)) to see what people are doing in areas like controlling RC cars and remotely locking doors.
- [This article](http://electronicdesign.com/archive/whatever-happened-electronics-hobbyist) is interesting reading, and might provide you insight on why a site like this one isn't the ideal place to start.

Subsequently, with some clarity on a project to take up, this site would be useful for asking specific questions around a problem being faced, so long as the questions demonstrate good initial effort towards solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

See if there is a hackerspace or other hobbyist group nearby. You'll meet people at all levels of expertise with varied onterests who will be only too willing to help you along. Plus you'd likely have use of a larger kit of tool than you'd likely want to own initially.

Answer (score 2):

Figure out what you have a passion for doing and start there. If it's photography, make camera control gadgets for panoramic pictures or remote control or automation for wildlife photography.

I can't see anyone get passionate about door openers but maybe that's just me...

But when you encounter difficulties **and you will**, that passion, whatever it is, will drive you on to actually get through them and get it working.

Plus that way you may discover a niche need that enough other people share, to build a viable product or business around.